# The difference between `ps axjf` and `ps -axjf`

Tags: ps, man

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of the `ps` command in linux.

I'm confused when using `ps axjf` and `ps -axjf` when I find they seem to have different meanings in the manual but their output is almost same.

What are the specific differences between them?

For these options, the manual says:

```
a      Lift the BSD-style "only yourself" restriction, which is imposed upon the set of all processes when some BSD-style (without "-") options are used or when the ps personality setting is BSD-like.  The set of processes selected in this manner is in addition to the set of processes selected by other means.  An alternate description is that this option causes ps to list all processes with a terminal (tty), or to list all processes when used together with the x option.

-a     Select all processes except both session leaders (see getsid(2)) and processes not associated with a terminal.

x      Lift the BSD-style "must have a tty" restriction, which is imposed upon the set of all processes when some BSD-style (without "-") options are used or when the ps personality setting is BSD-like.  The set of processes selected in this manner is in addition to the set of processes selected by other means.  An alternate description is that this option causes ps to list all processes owned by you (same EUID as ps), or to list all processes when used together with the a option.

j      BSD job control format.

-j     Jobs format.

f      ASCII art process hierarchy (forest).

-f     Do full-format listing.  This option can be combined with many other UNIX-style options to add additional columns.  It also causes the command arguments to be printed.  When used with -L, the NLWP (number of threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns will be added.  See the c option, the format keyword args, and the format keyword comm.
```

Especially for the `f` and `-f` options, it seems that `-f` does not have the meaning of outputting hierarchical relationships.

I compared the output of these two commands and they are almost identical except for a few lines.

```shellsession
lightxy233@iZ8vb0rgcfh3yx60rzee1jZ:~$ ls
_axjf.txt  axjf.txt
lightxy233@iZ8vb0rgcfh3yx60rzee1jZ:~$ diff _axjf.txt axjf.txt
81c81
<       2  639305       0       0 ?             -1 I        0   0:00  \_ [kworker/u4:0-flush-252:0]
---
>       2  639305       0       0 ?             -1 I        0   0:00  \_ [kworker/u4:0-events_unbound]
126,127c126,127
<  630827  630830  630830  630830 pts/0     641497 Ss    1000   0:00  |       \_ -bash
<  630830  641497  641497  630830 pts/0     641497 R+    1000   0:00  |       |   \_ ps axjf
---
>  630827  630830  630830  630830 pts/0     641448 Ss    1000   0:00  |       \_ -bash
>  630830  641448  641448  630830 pts/0     641448 R+    1000   0:00  |       |   \_ ps -axjf
129c129
<  630845  641496  630845  630845 ?             -1 S     1000   0:00  |           \_ sleep 1
---
>  630845  641447  630845  630845 ?             -1 S     1000   0:00  |           \_ sleep 1
```

I think this may involve mixing different styles of ps commands, but I haven't found a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you’re using [procps-ng’s `ps`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps), this does indeed boil down to mixing different styles, and how `ps` interprets options. The key element in your commands is the use of the `x` option: since that only exists in BSD style, and is unambiguous in your command (because `-a` doesn’t take arguments), the whole set of options is interpreted in BSD style. As a result, `axjf` and `-axjf` enable the same set of options, and differences in output are caused by differences in processes.

If you drop the `x`, you’ll see the differences: `ps ajf` and `ps -ajf`.

The ambiguity around `x` shown in the `ps` man page involves the use of the `-u` option: if that’s interpreted in Unix style, it takes an argument specify the user. So `-ux` (and variants thereof such as `-aux`) is interpreted as `-u x`, unless there is no `x` user, in which case procps-ng `ps` applies a heuristic telling it to switch to BSD style.